# Debo hacer un Web Scraping con Python en un archivo externo

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scraping

Hola estoy comenzando con python y debo hacer un web scraping de olx de la sección de autos debo exportar la descripción y el precio de los vehículos, pero me arroja un error cuando quiero exportar la información en un archivo csv. Espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar mi problema, muchas gracias de antemano y quedo atento a sus respuestas.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.olx.com.ec/autos_c378')
url_page ='https://www.olx.com.ec/autos_c378'
page = requests.get(url_page).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
tabla = soup.find('figure',attrs='[@data-aut-id=itemImage]')

boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-aut-id="btnLoadMore"]')
for i in range(3): # Voy a darle click en cargar mas 3 veces
    try:
        # le doy click
        boton.click()
        # espero que cargue la informacion dinamica
        sleep(random.uniform(8.0, 10.0))
        # busco el boton nuevamente para darle click en la siguiente iteracion
        boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-aut-id="btnLoadMore"]')
    except:
        # si hay algun error, rompo el lazo. No me complico.
        break

    autos = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@data-aut-id="itemBox"]')
    for auto in autos:
        precio = auto.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@data-aut-id="itemPrice"]').text
        descripcion = auto.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@data-aut-id="itemTitle"]').text
        #print(descripcion, precio)
        with open('autos.csv','a') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerow([precio, descripcion, datetime.now()])
```

Comment: Si nos dices cual es el error sería un gran avance ...

Comment: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
ese es el error sale en la linea 20

Comment: Significa que no tienes las librerías necesarias para usar beautiful soup, intenta con pip install lxml